# How can I do this with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL and have two database tables as follows:

**Users**

```
id   username
--------------
1    Bill
2    Steve
```

**Objects**

```
user_id   key   value
----------------------
1         A     X
1         B     Y
1         C     Z
2         A     S
2         C     T
```

What query is required to produce the following result?

```
username   A  B  C
-------------------
Bill       X  Y  Z
Steve      S     T
```

I have tried this with an `INNER JOIN`, but end up with 5 rows (one for each corresponding object row).

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: here is one way [http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/creating-crosstabs-in-mysql.html](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/creating-crosstabs-in-mysql.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605604/mysql-pivot-query-results-with-group-by

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a MySQL query turn rows into columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336985/can-a-mysql-query-turn-rows-into-columns)

Comment: Can be called `Pivot` table or `Crosstab` report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select u.username
     , oA.value A
     , oB.value B
     , oC.value C
  from users u
left
  join objects oA
    on u.id = oA.user_id
   and oA.key = 'A'
left
  join objects oB
    on u.id = oB.user_id
   and oB.key = 'B'
left
  join objects oC
    on u.id = oC.user_id
   and oC.key = 'C'
```

Comment: this needs @ruakh warning too: If 'A', 'B', and 'C' are known beforehand

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. It was also faster than the sub-query method posted.

Answer (score 3):

If `'A'`, `'B'`, and `'C'` are known beforehand, you can do this:

```
SELECT users.username,
       ( SELECT objects.value
           FROM objects
          WHERE objects.user_id = users.id
            AND objects.`key` = 'A'
       ) AS a,
       ( SELECT objects.value
           FROM objects
          WHERE objects.user_id = users.id
            AND objects.`key` = 'B'
       ) AS b,
       ( SELECT objects.value
           FROM objects
          WHERE objects.user_id = users.id
            AND objects.`key` = 'C'
       ) AS c
  FROM users
 ORDER
    BY users.username
;
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this is not the query that you are asking for, but this is a clean and sipmle query that I have used in your situation:

```
select objects.*, matrix.*
from 
        (select users.id, o.key
          from users, (select distinct key from objects) as o
        ) 
as matrix left join objects on matrix.id = objects.user_id
                           and matrix.key = objets.key
order by matrix.id, matrix.key
```

This query "fills" the empty spaces. So you can consume the resultset with two nested foreach (or whatever similar) and draw the desired table.