# how do I concatenate rows in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-concat

```
table 1
--------
pid | name
1    someone
2    another


table2
--------
bid | valu
1     drum
2     guitar
3     flower
4     cake


table3
------
id | pid | bid | pref
1    1     3     yes
2    1     1     maybe
3    1     2     no
4    2     4     definately
5    2     2   
6    2     3     no
```

So as you can see I have 3 simple tables where the third one is used to create a mapping between table 1 and 2 along with some additional data. Now I need to write a query to display the `valu` and `pref` in a concatenated string based on the `pid`,

So against `pid = 1`, the expected output is something like
`flower yes, drum maybe, guitar no`....so How do I write this query?

I tried( pretty much a blind guess):

```
SELECT opa.name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(opb.valu,' ',opc.pref) SEPARATOR ',') AS myChoice
 From
     table_1 opa
 INNER JOIN table_3 opc ON opc.pid = opa.pid
 INNER JOIN table_2 opb ON opb.bid = opc.bid
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336985/can-a-mysql-query-turn-rows-into-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your query is right you just forgot the `GROUP BY`

```
 SELECT opa.name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(opb.valu,' ',opc.pref) SEPARATOR ',') AS myChoice
 From
 table1 opa
 INNER JOIN table3 opc ON opc.pid = opa.pid
 INNER JOIN table2 opb ON opb.bid = opc.bid
 group by opc.pid
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d10d/2)