# convert column to row crosstab in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to my to create cross tab in MySQL.

There are 2 tables TABL1 AND TBL2, I don't know how to convert column to rows.

Please give me a solution.

My coding as the following:

select * from TBL1 t1 left join TBL2 t2 on t1.des=t2.des ;

```
TBL1 :
DES
A
C
D
E

TBL2
ID DES
1  A
2  C
3

RESULT THAT I NEED

ID   A   C  D  E
1    1
2        1
3
```

Regards,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336985/can-a-mysql-query-turn-rows-into-columns this might help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    t2.id,
    SUM(IF(t1.des IS NOT NULL AND t1.des = 'A',1,0)) as 'A',
    SUM(IF(t1.des IS NOT NULL AND t1.des = 'C',1,0)) as 'C',
    SUM(IF(t1.des IS NOT NULL AND t1.des = 'D',1,0)) as 'D',
    SUM(IF(t1.des IS NOT NULL AND t1.des = 'E',1,0)) as 'E'
FROM
    TBL2 t2
LEFT JOIN TBL1 t1
    ON t2.des = t1.des
GROUP BY
    t2.id
```

Comment: @JamDara in mysql you cannot pivot the data in a dynamic manner you have to manually do it... or better yet generate the query from a script

Comment: I agree with @Stephan, I had this similar problem with our oracle database. You can't just dynamically transform row value as field.

Answer (score 0):

For some automatization you can try to use next steps:

1. make a cursor for reading your TBL1 - so you will know how many cols you have

   ```
   DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT des FROM TBL1;
   ```
2. inside the cursor you need to make a dynamicSQL for a Select statement. someting like these:

   ```
   ....
   FETCH curs INTO cDes;
   ....
   set @sel = concat(@sel, 
   ', SUM(IF(t1.des IS NOT NULL AND t1.des = ''', cDes,''',1,0)) as ''',cDes, '''');
   ...
   CLOSE curs;
   ```
3. after you have done it you need to complete a full version of your dynamicSQL. something like these:

   ```
   set @crosstab = concat('select t2.id', @sel, 
                           'FROM TBL2 t2
                           LEFT JOIN TBL1 t1 ON t2.des = t1.des
                           GROUP BY t2.id');

   PREPARE STMT FROM @crosstab;
   EXECUTE STMT;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
   ```