# Join 3 tables into multiple columns of the first table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to normalise my tables and use 3 different tables instead of just one huge one (because everybody has told me that normalising is the right thing to do). However, I am hitting a stumbling block. I have 3 tables: topics, sides, rows.

```
TOPICS:
id | topicname | topicdescription

ROWS:
id | topic_id | rowname | rowdescription

SIDES:
id | topic_id | sidename | sidedescription
```

One topic can have multiple rows and multiple sides.

I would like to join the tables so that I have this master result (or something like it:

```
RESULTTABLE: 
topic_id | topicname | topicdescription | rowname0 | rowdescription0 | rowname1 | rowdescription1 | .... | sidename0 | sidedescription0 | sidename1 | sidedescription1 |...
```

I do not know how many rows or sides each topic will have in advance, and all the solutions I've seen on stackoverflow thus far have required me to know in advance exactly how many rows and sides I will have before I do the join call.

This is what I tried and the result was NOT what I wanted:

```
SELECT topics.id, topics.topicname, topics.topicdescription , 
       sides.sidename , sides.sidedescription, rows.rowname , 
       rows.rowdescription  
FROM `topics` 
 INNER JOIN sides 
 ON sides.topic_id = topics.id 
 INNER JOIN rows 
 ON rows.topic_id = topics.id WHERE topics.id=1
```

This creates a table with multiple rows (which I do not want), not one with multiple columns.

Background: I'm using mysql 5.5, php 5.4.

Comment: How is knowing the topic name and description per row and side useful?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I am trying to create a database for a debating website, where a topic can have multiple rows and multiple sides. So the data would eventually look like this:
1 | Should we debate this? | This is a meta-debate | team alpha | members of team alpha | team bravo | members of team bravo | .... | yes | supporters of the topic | no | opposers of the topic |

Comment: Ah, I see. You want to flatten the structure. Yeah, don't do that.

Comment: @GK79 why you don't used group_concat to get them with comma or other sembole separated?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - why not? I'm here to learn, and I was told that my original table (which was a flat structure) was wrong so I should normalise it. Now I'm normalising and want to get the data from there but that is also wrong?

Comment: You don't denormalize the data to access it, you access it in a normalized manner.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized how I missunderstood your question.

This topic should lead you to the desired result: [Can a MySQL query turn rows into columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336985/can-a-mysql-query-turn-rows-into-columns)

What you really need are pivot tables: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

Comment: My key problem is that I need to know exactly what you would have put in the place where you wrote "[etc]". If I don't know how many rows or sides exist, how do I do the left join such that they all become columns within the same table, and not multiple rows of a table (which your solution will lead to).

Comment: Thanks. I'll go and research that area more to see if that has the solution.

Comment: Nobody needs pivot tables

Comment: @Strawberry In order to achieve what he is aiming for... he does.