# MySQL Grid: daily sales vs region

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, self-join

I want to make a  MySQL query to obtain a grid with the sales per country or city day by day:

```
SELECT      DATE(creacion) as fecha,
            SUM(case when order_paid = 'Approved' and info_direccion_pais = 'GB' then 1 else 0 end) as sales_UK,
            SUM(case when order_paid = 'Approved' and info_direccion_pais = 'AU' then 1 else 0 end) as sales_AU
FROM        orders
WHERE       DATE(creacion) >= '2015-01-01'
GROUP BY    fecha
ORDER BY    fecha DESC
LIMIT       0, 100
```

This code returns the structure the way I want it:

```
fecha   aprobadas_uk    aprobadas_au
2015-04-30  5   7
2015-04-29  2   9
2015-04-28  12  19
2015-04-27  4   22
2015-04-26  8   25
2015-04-25  1   9
2015-04-24  3   4
2015-04-23  3   11
2015-04-22  5   1
```

However I have to create one line for each one of the countries I have on the database records, which is a lot, even more in the case of the cities.

**How could I obtain all the countries or cities at once?**

Comment: What does your table structure look like ? Do you have only one table ? What should be the desired output of your query ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it works:

```
SELECT  DATE(creacion) as fecha, info_direccion_pais,
        SUM(case when order_paid = 'Approved' then 1 else 0 end) as sales
FROM        orders
WHERE       DATE(creacion) >= '2015-01-01'
GROUP BY    fecha, info_direccion_pais
ORDER BY    fecha DESC, info_direccion_pais
LIMIT       0, 100
```

This will have 3 columns: fecha, info_direccion_pais and sales. This will give country code so you can may be join it on another country table to get country name. Look at the changes that I made to `SELECT`and `GROUP BY` clauses. I am not sure but you can even get rid of the `LIMIT` clause entirely.

Comment: Note that DATE() will be less efficient than a range query.

Comment: Close enough Mr Maximus2012. I really appreciate your proposal. It's returning the records divided by dates and country at the same time, which is useful, but it generates the array with 3 columns as you described.

Comment: I was trying to generate as many columns as countries on the records, which might be a little bit more complex, I assume?

Comment: That is correct. One way to do it would be to do it manually the way you were trying to do in your question which is not a bad approach if you have only a few countries.

Comment: See if this question (and its answer) helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336985/can-a-mysql-query-turn-rows-into-columns I might have misunderstood your original question.