# How to convert a set of 4 rows to columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL question, and really have no Idea how to resolve it.

I have the following query:

SELECT p.nombre, ti.tallerhorario_id
FROM persona p, talleresinscritos ti
WHERE p.pasaporte = ti.pasaporte

At the result is this:

[image]

I'm looking to make a query in which the second column doesn't show as a row for every "tallerhorario_id", but for every "nombre".

For example:

EUCLIDES   | 7 | 24 | 32 | 48

LIZ LORENA | 4 | 18 | 33 | 47

Every person always have 4 rows associated, without exceptions.

Could you help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a MySQL query turn rows into columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336985/can-a-mysql-query-turn-rows-into-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to actually put the values in one column, using `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT p.nombre, group_concat(ti.tallerhorario_id)
FROM persona p JOIN -- LEARN TO USE PROPER EXPLICIT JOIN SYNTAX
     talleresinscritos ti 
     ON p.pasaporte = ti.pasaporte
GROUP BY p.nombre;
```

A comma-delimited list is not what you asked for, but it might solve your problem.  If you have an counter, say 1, 2, 3, and 4, the second table, then you can easily do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.nombre, 
       MAX(case when counter = 1 then ti.tallerhorario_id end) as id1,
       MAX(case when counter = 2 then ti.tallerhorario_id end) as id2,
       MAX(case when counter = 3 then ti.tallerhorario_id end) as id3,
       MAX(case when counter = 4 then ti.tallerhorario_id end) as id4
FROM persona p JOIN -- LEARN TO USE PROPER EXPLICIT JOIN SYNTAX
     talleresinscritos ti 
     ON p.pasaporte = ti.pasaporte
GROUP BY p.nombre;
```

Finally, if you don't have a counter, one way is to add one uses variables:

```
SELECT p.nombre, 
       MAX(case when counter = 1 then ti.tallerhorario_id end) as id1,
       MAX(case when counter = 2 then ti.tallerhorario_id end) as id2,
       MAX(case when counter = 3 then ti.tallerhorario_id end) as id3,
       MAX(case when counter = 4 then ti.tallerhorario_id end) as id4
FROM persona p JOIN -- LEARN TO USE PROPER EXPLICIT JOIN SYNTAX
     (SELECT ti.*,
             (@rn := if(@p = pasaporte, @rn + 1
                        if(@p := pasaporte, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as counter
      FROM talleresinscritos ti CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @p := '', @rn := 0) params
      ORDER BY ti.pasaporte
     ) ti
     ON p.pasaporte = ti.pasaporte
GROUP BY p.nombre;
```